# Member only User ID request form

Tags: civimember, joomla

We are a member organizations made up of other organizations.  We extend user logins to the members only section of our Joomla website to all staff members of our member organizations to access exclusive content.  Right now Organizations get an "Organization login" when they join, but to get staff their own logins to register for events and see content, they have to email or call.   We used to just use "Organization Logins" but that caused too many issues with data improperly being overwritten when registering for events (despite warnings on the forms).

I'd like to create a User ID Registration form that is only accessible behind the member paywall so that organizations can create logins for their staff. I created a profile with a user id creating required. What I've come up with so far isn't working because by requiring the Organization to login, when they get to the User ID creation form it wont create a new user ID because the organization obviously already has one. Any suggestions for getting around this?

Thanks.

Comment: This might require some programming. The other solution is probably to switch over to Drupal with CiviCRM. You can then use Webforms.
Another solution is to build a custom portal in Drupal with the CiviMRF drupal module which is talking to your joomla CiviCRM.